# Trying to add a Pandas series to a Dataframe left with blank values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a dataframe

```
       A
0    123
1    456
```

which I want to add the series 'B' to as a column:

```
       B  
520    111
132    444
```

to achieve this:

```
       A     B
0    123   111
1    456   444
```

'B' starts out with random indexes, so I reset them and tried something like this:

```
series_to_add = series_to_add.reset_index(drop=True)
df['B'] = series_to_add
```

When I print out the df however, B has nan values all the way down. I printed out the series_to_add and confirmed that all the indices got reset to 0,1,2,....

Comment: your code works for me I can't reproduce your error

Comment: Simpler method is `df['B'] = series_to_add.to_numpy()`